# Desenvolvendo Tema no Wordpress - Os widgets não aparecem

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou tentando desenvolver um tema, do zero, no Wordpress, acompanhando vídeo aulas. O problema não aconteceu apenas comigo, há pessoas comentando sobre o mesmo problema que é o fato de, depois de toda a codificação PHP, HTML e CSS voltados para a criação de widgets, eles simplesmente não aparecem.

```
/*Na página index.php*/
<div class="right_sidebar"><?php get_sidebar(); ?></div>

/*Na página function.php*/
<?php
    if(function_exists('register_sidebar'))
        register_sidebar(array(
            'before_widget' => '<div class="widgets">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ));
?>

/*Na página style.css*/
.sidebar .widgets{
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 18px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #CCC;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.sidebar .widgets h3{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #333;
}
```

Esse código parece não funcionar mesmo.

Grato desde já aqui.

Comment: Encontrei o motivo do "erro".

De fato, a versão utilizada pelas vídeo aulas estão ultrapassadas. Para ativar estas opções, as mais novas versões do WordPress possuem características próprias de ativação no momento do desenvolvimento do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A verdade é que nem é isso que falta.

O que está faltando é o arquivo sidebar.php "linkado" com a sidebar que você quer exibir. Eu geralmente utilizo assim:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ); ?>
</ul>
```

Lembrando que o right-sidebar é o id (ou name) da sua sidebar. Caso queira gerar sua própria sidebar, recomendo fortemente o site [GenerateWP](http://generatewp.com/).

Aí basta colar o código no seu functions.php:

```
// Register Sidebar
function custom_sidebar() {

    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'right-sidebar',
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar Direita', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );

}

// Hook into the 'widgets_init' action
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebar' );
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder.
De fato, realmente estava falando o arquivo criado dentro da pasta. É que na vídeo aula não demonstrava, passo a passo para criar esse arquivo e como recuperar esse arquivo na minhas páginas.
E darei uma olhada no GenerateWP.
Obrigado!